# Not able to update the array of objects where there is another array inside the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, redux, ecmascript-6

```
"departureList": [
    { 
        "fixDiscount":5.0,
        "endDate":"2021-08-25",
        "seatLeft":20,
        "addOn":[
            {
                "unit":1,
                "price":33.0,
                "name":"addone 1",
                "addonId":"5e826530-33c1-4300-ac0d-5ca85b2b2dbc"
            }
        ],
        "totalPeople":1,
        "cartId":"ebc40f12-8963-49c8-b624-173a4f1d0d39",
        "departureCartId":"84005195-e09a-46df-99a6-3d92a42c3b8f",
    }
]
```

I have array of objects inside departurelist. Inside that i have another array of objects names addOn. I can change departure list data and update
like :

```
  export const departureDatasChange = (departureData) => {
     async (dispatch, getState) => {
       const { getCartData } = getState().cart;

    let departureList = getCartData.departureList;
   departureList = departureList.map((item) => {
    return item.departureCartId === departureData.departureCartId
     ? departureData
     : item;
    });
```

but I am not able to change the addon data and map to the same departure list object.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t care what you wanna reach.
My guess is you want to add `item.addon` to `departureData.addOn`.

```
return item.departureCartId === departureData.departureCartId
 ? {…departureData, addOn: item.addOn}
 : item;
});
```